# How to avoid Await.ready in Scala while using Futures?

Tags: scala, future

I have following pseudo code.
Invoke `fetch`, `fetchRecordDetail`, `upload` and `notifyUploaded` functions in sequence. Each function returns a future event but the first functions returns Option[T], going forward(`fetchRecordDetail`, `upload` and `notifyUploaded`) calls I need to carry only Some[T] type and ignore None.

Unfortunately I was able to achieve the following output with too many `Await.ready` calls.

**Expected output**

notified List(UploadResult(a_detail_uploaded), UploadResult(c_detail_uploaded))

### **Code**

```
def fetch(id: String): Future[Option[Record]] = Future {
    Thread sleep 100
    if (id != "b" && id != "d") {
        Some(Record(id))
    } else None
}

def fetchRecordDetail(record: Record): Future[RecordDetail] = Future {
    Thread sleep 100
    RecordDetail(record.id + "_detail")
}

def upload(recordDetail: RecordDetail): Future[UploadResult] = Future {
    Thread sleep 100
    UploadResult(recordDetail.id + "_uploaded")
}

def notifyUploaded(results: Seq[UploadResult]): Future[Unit] = Future{ println("notified " + results)}

   val result: Future[Unit] = //Final call to 'notifyUploaded' goes here

    Await.ready(result, Duration.Inf)
```

Can someone help to improvise this code by avoiding `Await.ready` calls.

```
val ids: Seq[String] = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d")
def filterSome(s:String) = fetch(s) map ((s, _)) collect { case (s, Some(v)) => v }
val validData = ids map filterSome
Await.ready(Future.sequence(validData), Duration.Inf)
val records = validData.map(_.value.get.toOption)
val recordDetails = records.flatten map fetchRecordDetail
Await.ready(Future.sequence(recordDetails), Duration.Inf)
val uploadResult = recordDetails.map(_.value.get.toOption).flatten  map upload
Await.ready(Future.sequence(uploadResult), Duration.Inf)
val seqUploadResult = uploadResult.map(_.value.get.toOption)
val result: Future[Unit] =  notifyUploaded(seqUploadResult.flatten)
Await.ready(result, Duration.Inf)
```

Comment: Compose rather than await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
Future.sequence(ids.map(fetch))                             //fetch Recs
  .map(_.flatten)                                           //remove None
  .flatMap(rs=> Future.sequence(rs.map(fetchRecordDetail))) //fetch Details
  .flatMap(ds=> Future.sequence(ds.map(upload)))            //upload
  .flatMap(notifyUploaded)                                  //notify
```

It returns a `Future[Unit]` which you *could* `Await()` on, but I don't know why.

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove the Await call at last(Don't use at all and print the result onComplete)? If I don't use the Await() call I see programme exit with out any  output.

Comment: Actually, that's the one situation where you really do need to `Await()` on a `Future`. If your program has nothing more to do then it really _should_ wait for all futures before exiting.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that is what do you want?:

```
  for {
    f1 <- validData
    f2 <- recordDetails
    f3 <- seqUploadResult
  }yield f3
  onComplete(notifyUploaded(seqUploadResult.flatten))
```

Comment: Doing that I'm getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get`. Its because none of the `Future` objects are giving any `Promise` by the time the code executes any of the variables in above for loop.

Comment: I see. I´ll check it